# Inseparable field extension of degree 2

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, separable-extension

I have searched for an example of a degree 2 field extension that is not separable.

The example I see is the extension $L/K$ where $L=\mathbb{F}_2(\sqrt t), \ K=\mathbb{F}_2(t) $ where $t$ is not a square in $\mathbb{F}_2.$

Now $\sqrt t$ has minimal polynomial $x^2-t$ over $K$ but people say that $x^2-t=(x-\sqrt t)^2 $. But wouldn't this when expanded be $x^2+t$?

How does this make sense?

Comment: In characteristic $2$, $-t=t$. That is, $x^2+t=x^2-t$.

Comment: How to see this?

Comment: $1+1=0$, so $1=-1$.